# Migrated question that might have been relevant on here

Tags: discussion

Just seen this question:

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/39823/10902

migrated from here to Engineering.

I added a comment that the most similar application of that sort of safety was in car window motors that stop and open the window if it detects an obstruction. As that is likely based on the electrical load detection it may still be relevant on here.

Comment: And your question is? When questions are migrated , answers are not (they used to but there were too many complaints)

Comment: @VoltageSpike “it may still be relevant on here”.... So should it have been migrated? Should it be migrated back? Should it be re-opened?

Comment: It's not about electronics, so I would say 'no'. It's off topic here so it would have been closed had it stayed.

Answer (score -1):

I think the migration was ok. Just because one of the possible solutions *could* be related to electronics doesn't mean this is the best place. If someone suggests that load detection is the best option, OP can investigate and ask here if there's a problem with that particular method.

I should add that I personally would prefer *no* migrations but rather just closing questions and let OP decide what to do. A question written for one stack is unlikely to fit all the guidelines for a good question on another stack and should be rewritten.